# Formal language for describing variability of a random experiment

Tags: probability, random-variable, terminology, entropy, variability

I have a random experiment with its probability space $(\Omega, \cal{F}, P)$ but no random variable defined over it. Is there any formal language for describing the variability of the random experiment? E.g. I feel the following three experiments have increasing variability, but I am not sure how to formalize this feeling (or if you have a different feeling, how to formalize that):

1. $\Omega=\{\omega_1\}$, $\quad\ $ $Pr(\omega_1)=1$
2. $\Omega=\{\omega_1,\omega_2\}$, $Pr(\omega_1)=0.9$, $Pr(\omega_2)=0.1$
3. $\Omega=\{\omega_1,\omega_2\}$, $Pr(\omega_1)=Pr(\omega_2)=0.5$

I am not opposing to the idea of introducing a random variable if that helps. I am just saying there is none in the original setup.

Comment: Entropy comes immediately to mind, because the only thing that varies is the probability measure itself.  Is that the sort of thing you mean by "formal language"?

Comment: @whuber, yes, I think so. But when I checked [Wikipedia's entry on entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)), I found entropy defined on a random variable, not the underlying experiment, hence my question. Can entropy be defined without reference to a random variable?

Comment: This is an unfortunate case where Wikipedia fails us.  Entropy most fundamentally is a property of a discrete probability measure.  Everything else is derived from that concept.

Comment: @whuber, thank you! Occasions like this are one more reason for why I respect you so much and feel indebted! Are there any mainstream alternatives to entropy relevant to my question?

Comment: The concept of *comparison of statistical experiments* comes to mind. See the classical paper by [Blackwell (of Rao-Blackwell fame)](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bsmsp/1200500222). I don't have time for an answer now ...

Answer (score 1):

A salient candidate is **entropy**. For a random experiment $X$ with possible outcomes $\omega_1,\dots,\omega_n$ and the corresponding probabilities $P(\omega_1),\dots,P(\omega_n)$, entropy is defined as
$$
H(X) =-\sum_{i=1}^n P(\omega_i) \ln \left( P(\omega_i) \right).
$$
It measures the average level of "information", "surprise", or "uncertainty" inherent in the experiment's possible outcomes.

<sub>The fact that  [Wikipedia's entry on entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) defines entropy w.r.t. a random variable rather than the underlying experiment can be considered a failure. According to @whuber,</sub>

> <sub>This is an unfortunate case where Wikipedia fails us. Entropy most fundamentally is a property of a discrete probability measure. Everything else is derived from that concept.</sub>

Comment: Since entropy can be used as a measure of (bio)diversity, alternatively other measures of (bio)diversity could also be used. Obviously diversity is variation is variability! See for instance https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/483535/how-to-include-the-observed-values-not-just-their-probabilities-in-information/485555#485555

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, thanks! I have seen and upvoted that answer already before.